# Installing OS-programs in linux

Tags: linux, daemon, source, upgrade

A previous user asked [a question on where to install applications](https://serverfault.com/questions/96416/should-i-install-linux-applications-in-var-or-opt), and the answer spells out how the directories are used, however, as the answer says, when you use make install for a system daemon like sshd or ntpd it typically puts the results in /usr/local/sbin. The problem is that the original service is still present and running out of /usr/sbin. If you are building a new server daemon from source, how do you make it the active version? Do you overwrite/uninstall the original version? or do you leave the original as it is, and somehow point the system to your new version in /usr/local?

Answer (score 1):

So, when you compile a new SSH version for instance manually, you need to go into your sshd_config file and set the path for it, removing the old path, in your case sbin.

A default CentOS path is this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

So in your case, remove:

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

Then put in the config file your new path with a : to add to the path, or you can just force it to use 1 path. (You would have to put PATH=\xx\xx\xx and uncomment it to work also as the daemon reads this config file)

====

Alternatively, you can overwrite the original with the newer one, will have no issues with it, another point to make clear is that when you overwrite something, make a backup, obviously.