# A good place for application files in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I am rather new to Debian file system placing convention. I see that configuration files for applications are usually stored in /etc/{application_name}/

Is this a "go-to" place when storing actual files of the application?

Comment: Just for a thought, but look for an applications that uses a similar technologies to what you are creating that are already in the Debian repo.  Look at the structure and layout and then follow the examples from other applications.

Comment: Related (or perhaps duplicate): [Should I install Linux applications in /var or /opt?](http://serverfault.com/a/96420/218590)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packaged application have their own locations, typicall under `/usr/` or `/var/lib/`, with executables (or links to them) under `/bin/` or `/usr/bin/`

For self-compiled or self-written application, you can use `/usr/local/bin/` for the executables and `/usr/<appname>/` for the application itself (or its asset files).

Some more (albeit somewhat outdated) informations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: I guess you can find the most up to date and complete information in the official [refspec of the Linux Foundation LSB Workgroup](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/devel-manuals#policy). According to the section on [configuration files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-config-files), generally acceptable locations are `/etc` or `/etc/{app_name}`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by shodanshok `/usr/local` is a good place to store an application that is not a package (deb, rpm). Hovewer, if you would rather have your app in one directory (instead of /usr/local/etc for config files, /usr/local/bin for executables), you can place it in `/opt` directory. This is often the directory of choice in case of apps that come with their own custom installers.